# How to find what library name should I use

Tags: c++, c

I must add `-lm` in gcc command when using `pow`. One day when I was learning linux thread I saw I must add `-lpthread` in gcc command.
I know it might be impossible to find library name via function name. But **is there a way to find what library name should I add**? Maybe via the header's name? Now the only way I know is searching other's experience.

Comment: You will use the linux man pages. For example `man 3 pow` explains you must (1) `#include <math.h>` and (2) Link with `-lm`. Most libraries will have the filename `libxxx.so` where `xxx` could be for example `ssl` or `crypto`, etc... When you link with the library, you drop the `lib` part and include `-l`. (for example to use `libssl.so` you would use `-lssl`). That's pretty much it. This presumes your library search path is correct (which it will be by default for the normal c libraries)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into the documentation; for `man pow` you will read

> Link with -lm.

for `man pthread_yield` you will read

> Compile and link with -pthread.

Such a documentation does not exist everytime; you might have to look at other places too (e.g. pdf, info pages, web sites).